# VHDL code not interfacing with testbench correctly

Tags: floating-point, vhdl

I am trying to make a 32-bit floating point multiplier with *combinational* logic. 
So far as I can tell I have done so, except when I try to simulate my test bench in it. 
If I simulate with my code in, I get U's in ALL values. If I take my code out and simulate I get my input vectors. I know I haven't normalized my mantissa completely yet.
I can't understand why at all. Everything compiles perfectly. The only problem I am having is getting values when I simulate my test bench... 
Everything is calling everything correctly as well.
Any help would be much appreciated.

**Please note the test-bench does work, I have simulated it with other VHDL which did return correct values**

Here is my code for the multiplier:

```
library IEEE                   ;
use IEeE.std_logic_1164.all    ;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all   ;
use ieee.numeric_std.all       ;
Use Ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; 

entity FP_MULTIPLIER is
    port( A_VAL, B_VAL : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
            F_VAL : out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0));
end FP_MULTIPLIER;--

architecture Behavioral of FP_MULTIPLIER is
signal exponant : std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
signal holder : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA1 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA2 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA3 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA4 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA5 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA6 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA7 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA8 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA9 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal AD1  : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal AD2  : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal AD3  : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal almost:std_logic_vector (23 downto 0);
signal F0:std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal F1:std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
constant ZERO : std_logic_vector := "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";     --zero vektir for imputs

type temp_MP is array (6 downto 1) of std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal MP :temp_MP;
type temp_PPA is array (23 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);                         --creates 24 vectir array of 49 length
signal temp :temp_PPA := (others => (others => '0'));
begin

exponant(8) <= A_VAL(31) xor B_VAL(31);                                                         --gets sign bit
exponant (7 downto 0) <= ((A_VAL (30 downto 23) + B_VAL (30 downto 23)) - 127 );                --gets exponant

partial : for I in 0 to 23 generate
    temp(I) (23+I downto I) <= '1'& A_VAL(22 downto 0) WHEN B_VAL(I)='1' ELSE                   --fills vector array and shifts it properly
                                    (others => '0');
end generate partial;


RRU1 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (temp(0),temp(1),temp(2),temp(3),temp(4),temp(5),temp(6),PPA1,PPA2,PPA3);
RRU2 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (temp(7),temp(8),temp(9),temp(10),temp(11),temp(12),temp(13),PPA4,PPA5,PPA6);
RRU3 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (temp(14),temp(15),temp(16),temp(17),temp(18),temp(19),temp(20),PPA7,PPA8,PPA9);
RRU4 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (temp(21),temp(22),temp(23),ZERO,PPA7,PPA8,PPA9,MP(1),MP(2),MP(3));
RRU5 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (PPA1,PPA2,PPA3,PPA4,PPA5,PPA6,ZERO,MP(4),MP(5),MP(6));
RRU6 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (MP(1),MP(2),MP(3),MP(4),MP(5),MP(6),ZERO,AD1,AD2,AD3);
RRU32: entity work.RRU3_2 port map (AD1,AD2,AD3,F1,F0);

holder <= F1+ F0;    --implement with CSA?

almost <=   holder(46 downto 22) WHEN holder(47)='1' ELSE  --fix for rounding and radix point
                holder(45 downto 21);

F_VAL <= exponant & almost;

end Behavioral;
```

Here is the code for my test bench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use STD.TEXTIO.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.all;

entity ATB_FPM is
end entity ATB_FPM;

architecture ATB_FPM of ATB_FPM is

component FP_MULTIPLIER is
  port (
    A_VAL : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    B_VAL : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    F_VAL : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 )
  );
end component FP_MULTIPLIER;

type F_VALS_ARRAY is array ( 0 to 15 ) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
constant A_VALS : F_VALS_ARRAY := (
  X"3F800000", X"3F800000", X"3FA33333", X"38D1B717",
  X"41160000", X"41020831", X"43000000", X"40300000",
  X"47129320", X"41B80A3D", X"42C80000", X"46EC8E00",
  X"49791900", X"45800000", X"46733D52", X"390164EF"
);
constant B_VALS : F_VALS_ARRAY := (
  X"40000000", X"449F6000", X"42C80000", X"3951B717",
  X"460CAF00", X"42F61EB8", X"43800000", X"46210100",
  X"47000600", X"3B8B4396", X"43480000", X"4641BC00",
  X"3C4A42AF", X"46000000", X"44FC8666", X"3959945B"
);

signal X_A_VAL : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
signal X_B_VAL : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
signal X_F_VAL : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );

begin
UUT: FP_MULTIPLIER
  port map (
    A_VAL => X_A_VAL,
    B_VAL => X_B_VAL,
    F_VAL => X_F_VAL
  );

process
variable DLAY : TIME;
constant T50N : TIME := 50 ns;
file OUT_FILE : TEXT open WRITE_MODE is "results.txt";
variable BUF  : LINE;
constant SP2  : STRING( 1 to 2 ) := "  ";
constant SP4  : STRING( 1 to 4 ) := "    ";
constant HDR  : STRING( 1 to 38 ) := "  A_VAL     B_VAL       F_VAL     TIME";
variable LNO  : INTEGER := 1;
begin
   for I in 0 to 15 loop
     if LNO = 1 then
       LNO := LNO + 1;
       write ( BUF, HDR );
       writeline ( OUT_FILE, BUF );
     elsif LNO = 25 then
       LNO := 1;
     else
       LNO := LNO + 1;
     end if;
     X_A_VAL <= A_VALS(I) ;    X_B_VAL <= B_VALS(I);
     wait for 50 ns;
     DLAY := T50N - X_F_VAL'LAST_EVENT; 
   hwrite ( BUF, X_A_VAL );  write ( BUF, SP2 );
   hwrite ( BUF, X_B_VAL );  write ( BUF, SP4 );
   hwrite ( BUF, X_F_VAL );  write ( BUF, SP4 );
   write  ( BUF, DLAY    );
   writeline ( OUT_FILE, BUF );
   end loop;
end process;

end architecture ATB_FPM;
```

By popular demand, here is my RRU7to3;

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity RRU7_3 is
  port (
    A_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    B_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    C_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    D_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    E_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    F_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    G_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    F2_VEC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    F1_VEC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    F0_VEC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 )
  );
end entity RRU7_3;

architecture WASTEFUL of RRU7_3 is

component WTA7_3 is
  port (
    A  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    B  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    C  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    D  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    E  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    F  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    G  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    F0 : out STD_LOGIC;
    F1 : out STD_LOGIC;
    F2 : out STD_LOGIC
  );
end component WTA7_3;

signal ROW2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 65 downto 0 );
signal ROW1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 65 downto 0 );
signal ROW0 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 65 downto 0 );

begin

GEN_LABEL: for I in 0 to 47 generate
  WTAUNIT: WTA7_3
    port map (
      A  => A_VEC(I),
      B  => B_VEC(I),
      C  => C_VEC(I),
      D  => D_VEC(I),
      E  => E_VEC(I),
      F  => F_VEC(I),
      G  => G_VEC(I),
      F0 => ROW0(I),
      F1 => ROW1(I+1),
      F2 => ROW2(I+2)
  );
end generate;

  F0_VEC <= ROW0( 47 downto 0 );
  F1_VEC <= ROW1( 47 downto 1 ) & '0';
  F2_VEC <= ROW2( 47 downto 2 ) & "00";

end architecture WASTEFUL;
```

Now here is the RRU3to2

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity RRU3_2 is
  port (
    A_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    B_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    C_VEC  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    F1_VEC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 );
    F0_VEC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 47 downto 0 )
  );
end entity RRU3_2;

architecture WASTEFUL of RRU3_2 is

component CSADDER is
  generic (
    G_DELAY : TIME := 1 ns
  );
  port (
    A : in  STD_LOGIC;
    B : in  STD_LOGIC;
    C : in  STD_LOGIC;
    F0: out STD_LOGIC;
    F1: out STD_LOGIC
  );
end component CSADDER;

signal ROW1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 48 downto 0 );
signal ROW0 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 48 downto 0 );

begin

GEN_LABEL: for I in 0 to 47 generate
  WTAUNIT: CSADDER
    port map (
      A  => A_VEC(I),
      B  => B_VEC(I),
      C  => C_VEC(I),
      F0 => ROW0(I),
      F1 => ROW1(I+1)
  );
end generate;

  F0_VEC <= ROW0( 47 downto 0 );
  F1_VEC <= ROW1( 47 downto 1 ) & '0';

end architecture WASTEFUL;
```

I also edited my above FP_Multiplier to reflect changes made which were suggested for ease of reading (tested and compiles fine still, simply no values.)

Here is an image of simulation:

[image: simulation produced U's only & refuses to run]

Comment: The implementation you posted is pretty much meaningless without the definitions of RRU7_3 and RRU3_2.

Comment: They are simple 7 to 3 and 3 to 2 Row Reduction Units. They are not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a slightly complex problem of the vector arrays mismatching with the functions they were working on.  Fixing this, and also taking out where the vectors get "filled" with zeros; the code works now. **Note, it has not normalized the numbers yet however**
Though it does give a somewhat accurate number to a certain point.

**For those curious here is the somewhat working description**

```
library IEEE                   ;
use IEeE.std_logic_1164.all    ;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all   ;
use ieee.numeric_std.all       ;
Use Ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; 

entity FP_MULTIPLIER is
    port( A_VAL, B_VAL : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
            F_VAL : out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0));
end FP_MULTIPLIER;--

architecture Behavioral of FP_MULTIPLIER is
signal exponant : std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
signal holder : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA1 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA2 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA3 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA4 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA5 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA6 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA7 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA8 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal PPA9 : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal AD1  : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal AD2  : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal AD3  : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal almost:std_logic_vector (23 downto 0);
signal there: std_logic_vector (23 downto 0);
signal F0:std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal F1:std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
constant ZERO : std_logic_vector := "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";     --zero vektir for imputs

type temp_MP is array (6 downto 1) of std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);
signal MP :temp_MP;
type temp_PPA is array (23 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);                         --creates 24 vectir array of 49 length
signal temp :temp_PPA := (others => (others => '0'));
begin

exponant(8) <= A_VAL(31) xor B_VAL(31);                                                         --gets sign bit
exponant (7 downto 0) <= ((A_VAL (30 downto 23) + B_VAL (30 downto 23)) - 127 );                --gets exponant

partial : for I in 0 to 23 generate
    temp(I) (23+I downto I) <= '1'& A_VAL(22 downto 0) WHEN B_VAL(I)='1' ELSE                   --fills vector array and shifts it properly
                                    (others => '0');
end generate partial;


RRU1 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (temp(0),temp(1),temp(2),temp(3),temp(4),temp(5),temp(6),PPA1,PPA2,PPA3);
RRU2 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (temp(7),temp(8),temp(9),temp(10),temp(11),temp(12),temp(13),PPA4,PPA5,PPA6);
RRU3 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (temp(14),temp(15),temp(16),temp(17),temp(18),temp(19),temp(20),PPA7,PPA8,PPA9);
RRU4 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (temp(21),temp(22),temp(23),ZERO,PPA7,PPA8,PPA9,MP(1),MP(2),MP(3));
RRU5 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (PPA1,PPA2,PPA3,PPA4,PPA5,PPA6,ZERO,MP(4),MP(5),MP(6));
RRU6 : entity work.RRU7_3 port map (MP(1),MP(2),MP(3),MP(4),MP(5),MP(6),ZERO,AD1,AD2,AD3);
RRU32: entity work.RRU3_2 port map (AD1,AD2,AD3,F1,F0);

holder <= F1+ F0;

almost <=   holder(46 downto 23) WHEN holder(47)='1' ELSE
                holder(47 downto 24);

F_VAL <= exponant & almost (22 downto 0);

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is not written to be easily understood, and there are many possible improvements.

But I suspect the most important point is : as far as I can see, you are only assigning part of each partial product in the array called "temp", leaving the rest of each partial product "UUUU". We only have your assurance that the RRU units "work" and no way of telling if they are resolving these "UUU" input values into "UUU" on their outputs; it seems likely that they are. You would be recommended to assign defined values to ALL of each "temp" value. That might be enough to resolve the difficulty, but only you can tell unless you update the question with the missing information.

Further improvements :

1. why not call the partial product array something like `partial_products` instead of `temp`?
2. Why not call the sign bit `sign` instead of `temp_man(8)`? Ditto exponent, and `a_mantissa`  instead of `'1'& A_VAL(22 downto 0)`
3. As vermaete said, use the standard library `numeric_std` instead of std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned (which probably contradict each other). Then declare your unsigned quantities (like the partial products) as "unsigned" instead of slv.
4. Unless you intend to modify the value of `ZERO` (!) declare it constant instead of signal (and the `(others => '0')` form saves counting all those digits!).
5. Note that the two slices from `holder` you assign to `almost` are different sizes. If, as you say, "everything compiles perfectly" in this state, please file a bug report against the tool you are using, and post its name and version here so that we can avoid using it.

Comment: My apologies, I know it isn't super easy to understand. It was written without thought of anyone looking at it. 

If I instantiate that the temp arrays are all zero's before I begin filling them, I still get U's. 

As for further improvements, I like how I had it that way I don't have to add another concatenation for sign and exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Your testbench should drive at least the inputs of the FB_MULTIPIER component (a.k.a the [DUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_under_test)).
In the better case, it will also read the outputs of the DUT and check them if they are expected.

In your testbench, I could not find a place where you assign a value to X_A_VAL and X_B_VAL.  If you don't drive a std_logic, it will be in the Uninitialized state ('U').

And as a sidenote:

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all   ;
use ieee.numeric_std.all       ;
Use Ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Is a mix of old-style and new-style libraries.  You can find more information about it in the [VHDL FAQ](http://www.vhdl.org/comp.lang.vhdl/FAQ1.html#4.11).  But I would advise you not to do it and only use the `use ieee.numeric_std.all`

Comment: I assign values to X_A_VAL and X_B_VAL right after begin. In the UUT. Right before I assign X_F_VAL infact. They have values. The only time I can't see the input values is when I try to simulate with FP_Multiplier's architecture. I see what you're saying, but they are assigned...

Also; thanks for the note about the libraries.

Comment: sorry, I've missed that part.  I was reading it before my morning coffee.